# ANTLR4: Use getText() in label of python

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-construction, antlr

I'm currently having one issue with ANTLR4. I have previously worked with ANTLR4 and generated the classes in Java. I would then be able whenever I found a label to do: ctx.label.getText() to get the text in the label.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing in Python3, however, it is not working. 
For example in this grammar when I try to access the value.

```
expression
    : LPARENS expression RPARENS       
    | ...                                     
    | value=(INTEGER | FLOAT | BOOLEAN | STRING | HOLE)                         
    ;
```

When trying to access ctx.value.getText() it gives me the following error:

> print(ctx.value.getText())
>   AttributeError: 'CommonToken' object has no attribute 'getText'

Since I'm pretty new in using antlr4 with python was wondering what workaround exists for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of tokens, `value=TOKEN`, it’s `.text`:

```
print(ctx.value.text)
```

In case of a parser rule, `value=expression`, then it is `value.getText()`, I believe.

Comment: Finally, thank you so much. You don't know how much I have searched in stackoverflow and antlr.